# How to hook into debug.log?

Tags: errors, wp-error

I know that WordPress somehow with propers flags in `wp-config.php` direct errors to `error.log. I want to get notified when an error happens and logged in this file. I was going to monitor it, but if there is a way to hook into the error_log or something to accomplish this will be great.

The reason for this is that I want to submit these errors to third-party service. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress tells PHP, using [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), in [`wp_debug_mode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_debug_mode/) which errors should be handled and which file they should be written to. The function is called in `wp-settings.php` when WP is starting up.

As suggested by David in [How to catch all PHP errors with custom error handler?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166206/how-to-catch-all-php-errors-with-custom-error-handler) answers you could use PHP's [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to define a custom error handler for sending the errors to somewhere else.

Then there's the [WP_Fatal_Error_Handler](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_fatal_error_handler/) which WP attaches to PHP via [`register_shutdown_function()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) with [`wp_register_fatal_error_handler()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_fatal_error_handler/) - also in `wp-settings.php`.

Apparently the error handler can be extended, which means that you could use a child class to send the errors to the 3rd party service.

> A drop-in ‘fatal-error-handler.php’ can be used to override the
> instance of this class and use a custom implementation for the fatal
> error handler that WordPress registers. The custom class should extend
> this class and can override its methods individually as necessary. The
> file must return the instance of the class that should be registered.